# How to limit max width of UILabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, uistoryboard

There are a UILabel in the center of the UIView, named nicknameLabel, and will append a gender image after the nicknameLabel.

But when the nicknameLabel has a lot of text, it will beyond the bounds of the UIView.

[image]

So, how to limit max width of UILabel?

BTW: I using the storyboard. Thanks.

Comment: Give the label a <= width constraint.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Give the label a **<=** constraint like this:

[image]

Comment: Something so useful but I failed to notice for so long! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

use following `code` and set your `width` in `boundingRectWithSize` value.

```
CGSize itemTextSize = [@"Your Text" boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 30) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.5]} context:nil].size;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using constraints then remove all constraints from you label.

[image]

Then again set frames of your label and if you want to make multiline label, then simply set the number of lines from 1 to 0 and increase the height of your label.

[image]

OR

If you want to fit your text within the label.You can simply enable Autoshrink property.

[image]